# wp homepage links are not working

Tags: wordpress

I am facing a problem in my WordPress site( www.miu.edu.pk ) after editing .htaccess file, When I click on any link/button on homepage it brings me to homepage again instead of bringing me to the button link, menus are working fine but other link buttons on home page are not working.

Below is .htaccess file code.

```
# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /www.miu.edu.pk/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /naget/index.php [L] 
</IfModule> # 
END
```

Comment: Post your `.htaccess` file. Presumably there's an error caused by the edit but without seeing the code we can't determine what that is.

Comment: Actually, my ht access file was deleted and then I created that manually and  copied default code ..this is current code of my file 'code'# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /www.miu.edu.pk/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /naget/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
 I just changed the address in this line  like "RewriteBase /www.miu.edu.pk/"

Answer (score 1):

Your rewrite base is rather unusual. Rather than copy / manually modify some default code, go to Settings -> Permalinks in the admin and press save.

If WordPress has the necessary permissions it will write the .htaccess file for you. Otherwise it will provide the correct code for you to copy / paste into there.

Answer (score 0):

@nathan is absolutely right.

you can copy below code into your .htaccess file as another solution.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```